# create 301 redirect from subdomain to folder/page

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

Short story: I bought an expired domain (my first one) which is having nice backlinks pointing to subdomains and their pages - and I have created a blog on it.

It gets backlinks to:

- sub1.example.com -  sub1.example.com/page/
  sub1.example.com/page.html/ sub1.example.com/page/file.jpg
- sub2.example.com sub2.example.com/page/

So I want to benefit from all of the backlinks.

I have created a page on domain, like example.com/MYPAGE (wordpress) where I want to make all the redirects. On that page I have an article linked to other articles - however, those articles are not yet indexed even after 48 hours - that made me thinking there's something wrong with the redirect.

This redirect was made by someone from namecheap support and here's what he did:

1. created the subdomains: sub1.example.com and sub2.example.com
2. create a redirect IN cPannel from sub1.example.com to sub1.example.com/^/(.*)$
3. created an .htaccess file with this code in it.
   [image]

The redirect it works, but I am not sure if it gets any link juice.

(I guess, for now only subdomains are redirecting to MYPAGE, their pages are not)

How do I benefits from all these backlinks?
I know there must be an other 301 redirect code.

Many thanks!

Comment: Cross-site dupe on Webmasters SE: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/139451/create-301-redirects-for-subdomains-from-expired-domain-for-seo

Comment: `RedirectMatch` doesn't need `RewriteEngine On`. Also please clarify `I guess, for now only subdomains are redirecting to MYPAGE, their pages are not` with an example.

Comment: I thought sub.example.com/some-page is not redirecting to example.com/MYPAGE but it is. so what should I di?

Comment: I still need help. Even the redirect works, i am not sure will pass link juice from those backlinks...